# PHP use root namespace within another namespace without backslash

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I have a bunch of classes in my root namespace. I want to use them in another namespace but I can't figure out how to "include" them so that I don't have to add the backslash in the beginning.

```
class A {
    public static $a = 1;
}

namespace B {
    use \; // apparently invalid 

    class C {
        static function D { return A::$a; } // desired syntax
    }
}

\B\C::D(); // expected result is 1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: see [this section](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) of the manual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether the namespace is "root" or not, you cannot import an entire namespace using `use`. The best you can do is:

```
use A;
```

Comment: That is not true, I can almost bet I've seen imported namespaces in laravel

Comment: `use` is just *aliasing* names to other names. Yes, you can certainly alias a namespace, like `use Foo\Bar`, which is short for `use Foo\Bar as Bar`. However, you still have to write `Bar\Baz`, you can't just write `Baz` to use `\Foo\Bar\Baz`. I'm saying you cannot alias all classes in a namespace with just one `use` statement.

Comment: Oh well, it would be so awesome if I could.

Comment: That's unfortunately simply not how PHP works. Namespaces are just a layer on top of symbols (class names and such). A namespace cannot know all the classes that are in it, because PHP typically (auto)loads classes when they're first used, not when you write the `use` statement. PHP's namespaces are not a module import system.

Answer (score -1):

Change your `use` statement to

`use \A` -

And then you'll get your desired syntax -

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd get answers like that so I mentioned "a bunch of classes".

Comment: The leading ``\`` is superfluous. It's just `use A`.